# Density grouping of android

Tags: android, screen

```
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
```

scroll down a bit and you will see this part of the documentation

"
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
"

my question is what if the screen is smaller that 426x320, let say the screen have 240x160
which group it belongs to ?
It can't be in 'small' group cause it is not at least 426x320...

than where it is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a blog of Deanne that says 
"small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp. (Android does not currently support screens smaller than this.)"

so the answer is the resolution can't be smaller than 426dp x 320dp.